# How can I remove a PDF in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, pdf, books

There are several PDF files which I imported into iTunes to read using iBooks.

However, **I cannot manage to remove them**. By default, iTunes handles the its media library automatically. The PDFs and iBooks are stored in:

```
~/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Books/
```

When I remove the PDF files here, they will still show up in iTunes.

How I remove their entries in iTunes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you not select the book and use <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Delete ⌫</kbd>?
You'll be presented with a choice to delete the book from the library, or move it to the trash:
[image]
You'll probably want to move it to the trash, unless it's a PDF that you don't have somewhere else. Also, make sure that you are going to the books tab *on* your computer, not managing the books on your device.
Here:
[image]
Not here:
[image]

Comment: This does not work with my PDFs in iTunes 10.7.1.

Comment: @gentmatt What version of iTunes are you using? The current version is 10.6.1. I'm guessing 10.7.1 refers to your OS X version?

Comment: I meant 10.6.1 of course :P. Sorry!

Comment: @gentmatt That's really strange. What happens when you select the book and press Command + Delete?

Comment: When I select a book or PDF in iTunes, the file is highlighted blue as expected, but when I try to delete it the standard "does not work" sound plays.

Comment: @gentmatt Try doing it this way: 1) Select the PDF 2) Go to the Edit menu and select "Delete" Does that work?

Comment: The option is greyed out.

Comment: @gentmatt So lemme clarify: The PDF still shows up in iTunes, but you've removed the actual file that exists in the `~/Music/iTunes` folder. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, but it does not matter if the file is there or not.

Comment: @gentmatt Let's [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3239/discussion-between-daviesgeek-and-gentmatt)

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what is happening. I had this happen.

When you are trying to delete these items you are still in your device screen, not your actual Library.

Near the top right, where it says Devices, click eject. This will bring you back to your iTunes Library.

[image: eject]

Now, in the top left corner, select Books fro the drop-down menu. Now you can delete items from your Library permanently.

[image: drop down]